# Apache / PHP and dynamic CORS

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache, cors

I'm having a hard time to get around that CORS thing.

I have a javascript sending AJAX Put/Fetch requests to Apache/PHP script.

In this case, for the example, the javascript is running on CodePen,
and the Apache/PHP is on a local server.

I'm checking the origin against a list of allowed hosts.

It should be possible to let PHP return headers like:

```
$headers = getallheaders();

if ( checkorigin($headers['Origin']) === false) $headers['Origin'] = null;

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $headers['Origin']);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

This doesn't work.

Hard coding `https://s.codepen.io` into the header does work.

Ideas anyone ?

**Solution**

Changing from:

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $headers['Origin']);`

to:

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . "{$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");`

did the trick. Thanks to Rohit.007

Comment: try `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");`

Comment: Can't remember, but doesn't getallheaders return with the `HTTP_` prefix? Dump out `$headers` to see, also whats checkorigin?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone getallheaders returns ` $headers['Origin'] = https://s.codepen.io `.

Comment: @Rohit.007 That actually works, for some reason. Thanks.

Comment: That's great, I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");`

Comment: Yes. You got it :)